# Rails test fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The code works fine but i can't understand why the test fails.

This is my test:

```
 test "requires item in cart" do
    get :new
    assert_redirected_to store_path
    assert_equal flash[:notice], 'Your cart is empty'
  end
```

and this is the new action in Orders controller:

```
def new
    if @cart.line_items.empty?
      redirect_to store_url, notice: "Your cart is empty"
      return
    end

    @order = Order.new
  end
```

and i get an error:

```
"test_requires_item_in_cart", OrdersControllerTest, 2015-07-28 20:21:48 +0300]
 test_requires_item_in_cart#OrdersControllerTest (1438104108.20s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `line_items' for 3:Fixnum
```

models associations:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
```

and

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
```

I think the problem is that the test cannot recognize the association between @cart and line_items in controller.

Any help?

Comment: Where is `@cart` being defined? Also, your controller uses `store_url` and your test is using `store_path`

Comment: No, that's not it. In your test, ```@cart``` is set to *3*. Did you mean for ```@cart``` to be a record?

Comment: '@cart' is defined in a before_action :set_cart ` @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])`. The code works fine.

Comment: @SrdjanPejic i cant understand how it defined to 3 . the set-up for the test is this : `setup do
    @order = orders(:one)
  end` and :one is in fixtures file `one:
  name: MyString
  address: MyText
  email: MyString
  pay_type: MyString`